# wp_remote_post get user ids

Tags: php, wordpress, post

So I'm creating an admin wordpress site for an app.  I need to use wp_remote_post
to return userIDs. The picture is a google chrome extension, "advanced rest client". 
I'm new to wp_remote_post, I was given this {"type":"admin","function":"getUsers"} by someone else working on it.

I'm having a lot trouble finding help with this. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong.

So basically my question is how do I do what happened in the rest client but in  a wordpress post.

```
$users=array();
$args=array(
'body' => array(
'type' =>'admin',
'function' => 'getUsers'
));

$url = '{insert my sites api};
$users =  wp_remote_post($url, $args);
print_r($users);
```

[image]

Please help. And thank you.